# How to share Power Automate flows without sharing connections

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have created a set of flows in Power Automate assuming that I would be able to share the flow with other users.  The problem is that the flow seems to have my connections and credentials attached to it. So, the flow will activate from emails in my inbox, send messages from my account to my contacts, etc.

I want to be able to hand over this flow and have it automatically reconnect to the users similar connections with their own credentials.

Any help with this? Am I missing something?

I have tried sharing, copying, exporting, and adding new owners. They all seem to need access to my credentials to run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe its possible to have it automatically reconnect the connections, the way to do it is to export it and for the other person to setup their own credentials on import. https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).